# Control reaches end of non-void function in C

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, pointers, mpi

I want to check if an array is sorted in C in acs or desc order.
Here is the result of compilation using mpicc -Wall -o file file.c since I am using MPI library later in the code.

```
mypractice1.c: In function ‘isSorted’:
mypractice1.c:38:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
 }
 ^
/usr/bin/ld: unrecognised emulation mode: ypractice1
Supported emulations: elf_x86_64 elf32_x86_64 elf_i386 elf_iamcu i386linux elf_l1om elf_k1om i386pep i386pe
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Here is my code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <mpi.h>



//Function to check the order

 int isSorted(int size, int array[]) {

   if(size<=1) 
    return 1; //is ordered
    int i;
    for(i = 1; i < size; i++){
    if(array[i] >= array[i-1])
        return 1; //is Sorted ascending
    else if (array[i]< array[i-1])
return 2; //is sorted descending
else return 0;  //is not ordered
}
}
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Please specify which problem you see. Now the question says "doesn't compile very well", but you can make it much clearer by quoting a compilation error message. Please also show in which line the compiler complains (e.g. if it says "line 15", add a comment in your code saying "line 15 is here", so the people will see it easily).

Comment: `int *orden = isSorted(num_elements_per_proc, buffer);` - orden is a pointer to int and isSorted returns int

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't compile very well? It either compiles or it doesn't.

Comment: `randomNumbers()` does not return anything. Try to compile with `-Wall` and fix all the warnings first.

Comment: This is namely a segmentation fault.

Comment: Why care you using a recursive function rather than an iterative function?  Are you running out of Stack because of that?  Try replacing your function with a simple iterative version and see whether that resolves the problem?   If it works at small sizes ( hundreds of rows) but not at large sizes (millions of rows), that would be additional grounds for suspecting the problem is a stack overflow caused by recursion.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet how can I compile with -wall? I use mpicc -o file file.c

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I used an iterative function. The error is the updated one. I edited the question.

Comment: `mpicc -Wall -o file file.c`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say you have:

```
// Function to check the order

int isSorted(int size, int array[])
{
    if (size <= 1)
        return 1; // is ordered
    for (int i = 1; i < size; i++)
    {
        if (array[i] >= array[i - 1])
            return 1; // is Sorted ascending
        else if (array[i] < array[i - 1])
            return 2; // is sorted descending
        else
            return 0; // is not ordered
    }
}
```

You can't afford to return on checking only the first two values.  You should probably define whether you expect the data to be sorted in ascending or descending order, and verify that's what you've got, but if you really want to analyze which order the data is in, then you might use:

```
// Function to check the order
//  0 all equal
//  1 non-decreasing (ascending)
//  2 non-increasing (descending)
// -1 inconsistent (some ascending, some descending)

int isSorted(int size, int array[])
{
    if (size <= 1)
        return 1;      // is ordered; deemed ascending

    int num_eq = 0;    // Number of adjacent pairs that are equal
    int num_lt = 0;    // Number of adjacent pairs sorted ascending
    int num_gt = 0;    // Number of adjacent pairs sorted descending

    for (int i = 1; i < size; i++)
    {
        if (array[i] > array[i - 1])
            num_gt++;  // is sorted ascending
        else if (array[i] < array[i - 1])
            num_lt++;  // is sorted descending
        else
            num_eq++;  // is not ordered
    }

    assert(num_gt + num_lt + num_eq == size - 1);

    if (num_gt == size - 1)
        return 1;      // ascending with all unique
    if (num_lt == size - 1)
        return 2;      // descending with all unique
    if (num_eq == size - 1)
        return 0;      // all rows equal
    if (num_gt != 0 && num_lt != 0)
        return -1;     // inconsistent sorting
    if (num_gt + num_eq == size - 1)
        return 1;      // ascending with some equal
    if (num_lt + num_eq == size - 1)
        return 2;      // descending with some equal
    return -1;         // can't happen?
}
```

There are other ways to do this, but it is fairly simple to explain with the tail comments.  It would be feasible and clear to use an `else if` chain in the  tail of the function.  It has some advantages.  You could encode more return values to distinguish between strictly ascending and non-decreasing, or between strictly descending or non-increasing.

Comment: Why is assert for? Is it nreally necessary? It is giving me compilation problems

Comment: Then remove it.  But `assert()` is a standard macro from `<assert.h>` and shouldn’t give problems.